# Google Data Studio - filter based on events

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I'm trying to use multiple filters for the same chart and those filters are based on event labels. The issue I'm facing is that every filter works individually without any problem but if I select one filter, the other filters are empty.

Here is setup example.

I have events like this

```
(category -> action -> label)
flights -> origin -> <variable> (ex : barcelona)
flights -> destination -> <variable> (ex: new york)
```

In data studio I add a filter based on:

```
Dimension: event_label
Metric: total events
Filter: event action equals origin, event category equals flights
```

When clicking on this filter I see all the data I want to see

Then I add another filter:

```
Dimension: event_label
Metric: total events
Filter: event action equals destination, event category equals flight
```

When clicking on this filter i see all the data I want to see

So far so good...but it ends here

If I select one origin from the first filter, the second filter becomes empty while within the same session events feeding the destination have been recorded. In one session I could have Barcelona store in origin and New York stored as destination but when I select Barcelona in the filter Origin, nothing is displayed in the Destination filter.

I can mix filters with other types of data like mixing browser with source but I cannot mix events.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you apply filters together they join with the AND operation.
So you're limiting your data to events where the event action equals origin AND event action equals destination. This is always going to present 0 results, because both conditions don't exist at the same time.

Instead combine your filter conditions together in the same filter using the OR operator.

Comment: Hi Sian, that would make sense and explain why it doesn't work but how do you get all filters inside the same group to apply an "OR" condition instead of "AND" ? The display of label is already conditioned by a filter.

Comment: Create the filter with the following statements:
Include Event Category Equal to (=) flights
AND
Include Event Action In origin, destination

This will include any events where the category is flights and the action is either origin or destination.

Comment: Hi Sian, it seems to work but I'm wondering if there is no risk of getting the wrong data. There are common labels between origin and destination and when selecting them, I don't know if I'm selecting origin or destination. I have for example BRU, BCN, TXL in origin and the same in destination. If I pick BRU to start but could mean BRU as origin OR destination which means that the data might not be correct.

Comment: Have you tried adding the Event Action as a dimension in the table?

Comment: Hello Sian, if I do this, I only see origin and destination in the dropdown. I can add another dropdown with the list of destinations but this means that I cannot play with origin and destination pairs, I can only make one choice at a time.